# Why do this kind of tori are not manifold.

Tags: smooth-manifolds

A torus is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at a distance $b$ from the circle of radius $a$.

> I want to know why if $a=b$ or $b>a$ then the "torus" given is not a smooth manifold. I can figure it out intuitively speaking, but I want a formal argument.

Comment: Draw a picture. If b>a there is a clear self intersection, if b=a there is a cusp at the origin.

Comment: There is a way to say what you are pointing out in a formal language?

Comment: Is the question here: "Why is this not a torus, as in diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$?" or "Can this set be equipped with *any* smooth structure?".